# I want to mimic gradient colors, is there a tool or software that can help me figure out which colors I am creating and how?

Tags: user-interface, colors, user-experience, figma

For example, I do not know how to imitate the gradient colors in instagram.
Since I basically use figma, is there any tool to imitate gradient colors with figma plug-ins?
Just figuring out the colors, I can use a tool called `image Palette` to know the colors themselves. However, I don't know how to create a gradient (?). I don't know how to create gradients, etc.